# Monte Carlo Dropout implemented as subclass of tf.keras.Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.x

I am aware that one could implement Monte Carlo dropout by calling `model.predict()` multiple times and measuring the average of the return values. But, I wondered whether it would be possible to implement it through subclassing the `Model`s class of `tensorflow.keras`?

Using the more typical way of implementing models through subclassing the `Model`s class provides support for easy loading and saving of Keras models, without the need of any other code then calling `predict` at runtime (once). This might be especially useful when using Tensorflow Serving, but also already adds some comfort when loading it through some other Python script. (For example, when comparing multiple different models.)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this sample code should work:

```
class MonteCarloDropout(tf.keras.layers.Dropout):

    def __init__(self, rate):
        super(MonteCarloDropout, self).__init__()
        self.rate = rate

    def call(self, inputs):
        return super().call(inputs, training=True)
```

Then you can use this layer as any layer in your model..

```
...  
model.add(MonteCarloDropout(rate=0.2))  # just example... model is some Sequential model... could be anything...

...
```

I hope this helps!!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the posted custom layer serves another purpose. Using such a custom layer removes the necessity to call `model.predict()` with `training=True`. Setting `training=True` can be an issue when there are other layers that rely on alternative behaviour during training. However, using this layer does not answer the original question: you would still need to call `model.predict()` multiple times.